# How to move a File or Folder from source to destination using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

How do I move a File or Folder from source to destination using PowerShell?

In the below code, I want to move a file from `$destination` to `$newDestinationPath`

```
foreach($file in $fileList)
{
  $newDestinationPath = $destination + "\" + $newDestination

  New-Item $newDestinationPath -type directory

  // here I want to move file from $destination to $newDestinationPath 
}
```

I am new in PowerShell. Please help!

Comment: Get-Help Move-Item

Comment: @ZachAlexander I am writing script and integrating with TFS build. so i do not have any tool. Please tell me where I can execute this command?

Comment: `Get-Help` and `Move-Item` are built in cmdlets, just like `New-Item`.

Comment: @BenH Thank you! This command `Move-Item -Path C:\test.txt -Destination E:\Temp\tst.txt` works fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `move-item` cmdlet as for example `Move-Item -Path C:\test.txt -Destination E:\Temp\tst.txt`